# Need help converting 8 bit input into 3, 4 bit outputs

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

I have a midterm coming up on digital system design. My professor developed an ASM chart for a problem and I decided that I would try to fill out the code for practice. The simulation runs, it just gives an odd result. My first digit d2 cycles through 0-15 and the rest remain 0. I felt like I nailed everything, and I don't where I went wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   module b(clk,b,d1,d2,d0);
input clk;
input [7:0]b;
output [3:0]d0,d1,d2;
//reg[7:0]b;
reg [7:0]R=0;
reg [1:0]s=0;
reg [3:0]d2=0,d1=0,d0=0;
always @(posedge clk)
case(s)
0:begin s<=1;R<=b;end
1:if(b>90)begin s<=1;R<=R-100;d2<=d2+1;end else s<=2;
2: if(b>9) begin s<=2;R<=R-10;d1<=d1+1;end else s<=0;
default: s<=0;
endcase
endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module sim();
reg clk;
reg[7:0]b;
wire[3:0]d2,d1,d0;
b uut(.clk(clk),.b(b),.d2(d2),.d1(d1),.d0(d0));
localparam t=1;
initial begin clk=0; forever #(t/2.0)clk= ~clk;end
initial begin
#0.55 b=250;
end
endmodule
```

Slightly different code that also does not work.

```
module b(clk,b,d1,d2,d0);
input clk;
input [7:0]b;
output [3:0]d0,d1,d2;
//reg[7:0]b;
reg [7:0]R=0;
reg [1:0]s=0;
reg [3:0] dt2=0,dt1=0,dt0=0,d2=0,d1=0,d0=0;
always @(posedge clk)
case(s)
0:begin s<=1;R<=b;end
1:if(b>90)begin s<=1;R<=R-100;dt2<=dt2+1;end else s<=2;
2: if(b>9) begin s<=2;R<=R-10;dt1<=dt1+1;end else begin s<=0; d2<=dt2;d1<=dt1;d0<=R;end
default: s<=0;
endcase
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing b>90 and b>9 with R>90 and R>9.  Also, it looks like the first block of code you have never sets d0.

Comment: I fixed those careless mistakes and some progress has been made. Now two of the 3 outputs cycle through the numbers 0-15. `module b(clk,b,d1,d2,d0);
input clk;
input [7:0]b;
output [3:0]d0,d1,d2;
//reg[7:0]b;
reg [7:0]R;
reg [1:0]s=0;
reg [3:0]d2=0,d1=0,d0=0;
always @(posedge clk)
case(s)
0:begin s<=1;R<=b;end
1:if(R>90)begin s<=1;R<=R-100;d2<=d2+1;end else s<=2;
2: if(R>9) begin s<=2;R<=R-10;d1<=d1+1;end else begin s<=0; d0<=R;end
default: s<=0;
endcase
endmodule`

Comment: You should also reset d0, d1, and d2 to 0 in the first state.

Comment: Actually, I think your second block of code is better as it does not output 'intermediate' values for d0, d1, and d2.  Just make sure to compare with the correct reg and make sure to set the correct regs to 0 when you read in b.

Comment: I made some more adjustments and the code sort of works. The first loop has all three numbers match up to the input, but then the loop continues with some sort of pattern. I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: I tested the 2nd block of code you have posted in iverilog after making the changes I mentioned (compare with R instead of b and set dt1 and dt2 to zero at the same time b is loaded in to R), and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Finally got it to work, thanks alot for you help. About to start another practice problem, so hopefully you dont see right back on here.